# Why does pip fail with bad md5 hash for package?

Tags: python, django, hash, virtualenv, pypi

I'm trying to install Django package in a virtualenv. I'm on a new computer (OSX 10.8.2). I installed virtualenv via easy_install. With the virtualenv activated, I ran:

```
(pyenv)$ pip install Django
Downloading/unpacking Django
  Downloading Django-1.5.1.tar.gz (8.0MB): 2.0MB downloaded
  Hash of the package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=7465f6383264ba167a9a031d6b058bff (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/) (<md5 HASH object @ 0x108453df0>) doesn't match the expected hash 7465f6383264ba167a9a031d6b058bff!
Bad md5 hash for package https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.1.tar.gz#md5=7465f6383264ba167a9a031d6b058bff (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/Django/)
```

This happens even if I delete virtualenv and start over. I've tried again repeatedly over the past few hours, it always happens. Any suggestions?

Comment: Pip seems to have downloaded a corrupted package. There should be a pip temp folder in `/tmp`, in `<current folder>/build`, or in `~/.pip/cache/`. You have delete the corrupted package.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If it's just this package that you can't get to install, you could download the tarball manually, and then use pip to install it from that file.  The [Django download site](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/) has checksums that you can validate manually as well.  I don't use osx, but probably something like this would help:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/D/Django/Django-1.5.1.tar.gz
md5sum Django-1.5.1.tar.gz
pip install Django-1.5.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Neither `wget` nor `md5sum` are shipped with OS X.  `curl` and `md5` are available.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I used curl -O and skipped the validation.

Answer (score 18):

I have the same problem when I try `sudo pip install Pillow`, and I try `sudo pip install --no-cache-dir Pillow`, it works for me.

Comment: what is the meaning of no-chance dir

Comment: @ArpitSisodia https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594707/what-is-pips-no-cache-dir-good-for/45594808

Answer (score 5):

For me below command works

`pip install django --no-cache-dir`

Answer (score 5):

I now had this issue several times.

Like others mentioned before me, `pip install [module] --no-cache-dir`
helps most of the time.

But sometimes, you got some dependencies to install first and it fails installing one of these (md5 validation failed).

Just had this problem myself. In this case, **installing** this **dependency alone** like `pip install dependency`
**worked** and after that I was able to install the first module.

Also `pip install -vvv` is nice for more info gathering on general problem solving