# Error in installing Django

Tags: python, django

Today I wanted to install Django with steps of Django site, but when I installing that I get this error and searched but I couldn't find good answer:

```
Hash of the package https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=3c182cf9de00382ecf27fdc65fcfbe70 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/) (37e1d67ae64ad916aeb1e0b1f58a3b5e) doesn't match the expected hash 3c182cf9de00382ecf27fdc65fcfbe70!
Bad md5 hash for package https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.8.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=3c182cf9de00382ecf27fdc65fcfbe70 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/django/)
```

I use windows 10.

Comment: what's the command that you use to install it? BTW, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025788/why-does-pip-fail-with-bad-md5-hash-for-package

Comment: Can you update `pip` itself first: `pip install --upgrade pip` and then try again?

Comment: No, Give me that error

Comment: Give me this error:    'ip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: yet it's downloading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of things you can do. First, you can tell pip to ignore looking at the cache:

```
~$ pip install --ignore-installed Django
```

or you can try downloading the tarball instead:

```
~$ pip install https://www.djangoproject.com/download/1.8.5/tarball/
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because terminal is using cache version of Django for install. use below code

```
pip install django --no-cache-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error,I too got...This is due to the presence of a cache of Djanco.

`pip install django --no-cache-dir`

RECOMMENDED TO WINDOWS 10 USERS