# What is pip's `--no-cache-dir` good for?

Tags: python, docker, pip

I've recently seen the `--no-cache-dir` being used in a Docker file. I've never seen that flag before and the help is not explaining it:

```
 --no-cache-dir              Disable the cache.
```

1. Question: **What is cached?**
2. Question: **What is the cache used for?**
3. Question: **Why would I want to disable it?**

Comment: longshot on q3: to save up some RAM?

Comment: Documentation is pretty extensive on that one: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching

Comment: the first google result gives a pretty good description of it's usage https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

Comment: When you are building a docker image you want it to be light. This helps avoiding bloating the image with cached files.

Comment: @mikea Ironically, for `pip no-cache-dir`, this is now the first result.

Comment: Might be helpful to add a `docker` tag, since Docker is referenced by the question and most of the answers.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

1. **Cached is**: store away in hiding or for future use
2. **Used for**

- store the installation files(`.whl`, etc) of the modules that you install through pip
- store the source files (`.tar.gz`, etc) to avoid re-download when not expired

3. **Possible Reason** you might want to disable cache:

- you don't have space on your hard drive
- previously run `pip install` with **unexpected** settings

  - eg:

    - previously run `export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=nss` and `pip install pycurl`
    - want new run `export PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl` and `pip install pycurl --compile --no-cache-dir`
- you want to keep a Docker image as small as possible

**Links to documentation**

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching – @emredjan
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/ - @mikea

Comment: Why would I want to store the installation files?

Comment: To avoid downloading again and again. Suppose, you uninstall a module, when you install it next time, it will use the files from the cached dir

Comment: Ah, ok. So for a docker image which is only used for deployment (hence no "manual" actions") there is no reason not to use `--no-cache-dir`, correct?

Comment: Could these links be turned into html links?

Comment: @Hatshepsut Done!

Comment: @ozgur: I think you might have misread my comment. I argue as well that you should use the flag

Comment: Yes @MartinThoma, on a production docker image, you want to use pip --no-cache-dir, because no one else will install any packages, and storage space is even more valuable...

Comment: Haha I don't think the OP meant "what does 'cached' mean?" for question 1.

Comment: If you followed the bad practice of updating your development code without incrementing the version, it would use the cache rather than your new file.

Comment: another reason why you would  use `--no-cache-dir` https://intellipaat.com/community/9420/removing-pips-cache

Comment: Many of the links here have been moved in the docs. Latest as of 2021-09-16 is https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/.

Answer (score 181):

I think there is a good reason to use `--no-cache-dir` when you are building Docker images. The cache is usually useless in a Docker image, and you can definitely shrink the image size by disabling the cache.

Comment: you can use [`ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60270281/2248627) in docker for python 3.6.10 and higher images

Comment: Fwiw, with pip 18.1 you need to [set a falsy value](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#:~:text=falsy%20values) for that env var to work. For anything else I get a `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int` since the value gets parsed into a `posixpath`.

Comment: `RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` for docker images

Comment: Is this still important in **multi-stage builds**?

Comment: @AlexPeters Depends on how you make the multi-stage builds. I found the cleanest way is to install packages in builder image and copy the whole `site-packages/` to final image. This way you don't need to use any extra parameters of `pip` since the cache are not copied.

Answer (score 15):

Another reason to disable the pip cache - if you run pip as a user that does not yet exist, their home directory will be created, but owned by root.

This happens to us when building Amazon AMIs in a chroot - pip is being run as a user that exists on the builder machine, but not in the chroot jail where the AMI is being constructed. This is problematic as that specific user can now not ssh to what was just built as their .ssh directory is not readable by them.

I can't think of any other reason pip would be run as a user that doesn't exist though, so it's  very much an edge case.

Answer (score 9):

Reduce your docker image size if you're having python dependencies in your DockerFile, as your private registries/artifactories or your deployment servcies may have size limitation.

Answer (score 2):

I get permission error for installation of some pip packages if I don't use `--no-cache-dir` option.

```
Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml, bottleneck, nvidia-ml-py3
  WARNING: Building wheel for pyyaml failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.cache/pip/wheels/b1'
  WARNING: Building wheel for bottleneck failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.cache/pip/wheels/92'
  WARNING: Building wheel for nvidia-ml-py3 failed: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/.cache/pip/wheels/7f'
```

`chown /.cache` folder didn't help for some reason but with `--no-cache-dir` it works ok.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

From [fastapi official doc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/)

> The --no-cache-dir option tells pip to not save the downloaded packages locally, as that is only if pip was going to be run again to install the same packages, but that's not the case when working with containers.

Basically, there is no need to store whatever package cache you're installing locally since it is not required by docker containers.