# Whenever I try to install torch, it displays killed

Tags: python, pip, installation, pytorch

I just want to install pytorch, I ran this in the terminal:

```
pip install torch
```

And it displays:

```
Collecting torch
Killed
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

It says your your free ram is not enough to install the package, but there is a method that you can still use it.

```
pip install torch --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: Any hints as to the rationale why ignoring the cache reduces memory usage? Naively, I would assume that the cache only controls whether you have to download the package first

Comment: @TedBrownlow, not to store the downloaded files locally as you may not have enough memory on the device; also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45594808) has different explanations.

Comment: Aren't those points about storage rather than RAM?

Answer (score -2):

It suggests that the process is terminated, it may happen due to several reasons, one of them could be exceeding of memory usage. Check the GPU or CPU memory and ensure that it is not exceeding to the the available memory. Quick solution in that case would be a reboot.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Either improve or delete the answer